# Android browser call with POST?

Tags: android, android-studio, browser

i want to know if it's possible from an android app to call the Android browser  with a POST method and few parameters , possible ? and approx how to ? (Intent , action URL , post ? )

thanks ! ;-)

Comment: And what do you wanna post? And what should the Android browser do with the received/posted data? And.. what do you consider to be 'the Android browser'?

Comment: Posting is done to a server. And posting is done by browsers. It is unclear what you have in mind.

Comment: just one or two http custom parameters (body , name:value) , attended on the server side where a second dev team accept this parameters off course , sorry for the lack of description ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If by "call the Android browser", you mean launch a third-party Web browser app (e.g., Chrome, Firefox), then the answer is no, you cannot launch a third-party Web browser and have it execute a `POST` request.

Comment: ok, thanks for your reply. so is there a way to give parameters with a GEt or something else in the same case ? (App calling thrid party browser) except CGI URI because of some security reasons

Comment: @cremnet: "so is there a way to give parameters with a GEt" -- you can put query parameters on the URL that you put into the `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`, the same way that you would do in a link in a Web page. Overall, though, how a Web browser elects to handle that URL is up to the developers of the Web browser.